# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Designer Not Displaying Content Even Though It has Before

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-designer

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the Xamarin extension. I have encountered a problem where the Designer view is only showing white space and not the layout and content I added to the axml file. I tried searching for a solution to this problem and found one question relevant to mine—[Android Designer is not showing in Visual Studio Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857946/android-designer-is-not-showing-in-visual-studio-xamarin)—but it did not solve my problem because my axml is located in the Resources > layout folder. I opened my Solution the other day from the exact same hard drive and the Designer was showing all content correctly, but now my content is not showing. [This is an image of the Designer and axml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj1Xw.png)

Comment: What is the version of Visual studio? Have you tried to update Visual studio to the latest version?

Comment: Version 15.9.4. An update is available—I will update Visual Studio 2017 and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Updating the Version of Visual Studio 2017 did not make a difference.

Comment: You can try to create new project and see it has the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Version 15.9.7. Designer stays white after loading a layout file.
I could solv this by **disabling** "Enable Accelerated Rendering" in Preferences >> Xamarin.